# Getting error that file is in use on server but working fine on local system

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am confused whether it is a server issue or coding problem. My strong guess is that it might be a server issue because it is working fine on my local system.

I have upgraded a Asp.net 1.1 website to 4.0. In the application the a file is created by the values that the user enter on the forms. The file is saved in the attachments folder in the application. After the file is created the email is sent to the administrator with attaching the file as an attachment.

On my local system the email is sent just fine. As the application was built in 1.1 CDO is being used to send the emails. When I publish the application on server then attachment is failed and the following error is displayed,

```
The process cannot access the file 'E:\HostingSpaces\testuser\testapplication.mydomain.com\wwwroot\eTest\Attachment\4orsysil3dulr1iv1thvpade\ef_Comp.exp' because it is being used by another process.
```

I have given read, write, delete access to the attachments folder. If there is problem in the code then it should also effect the application on the local system too. I have checked all the StreamWriter is closed everywhere it is used.

If this is a server error then what could be the reason?

Edit:
The code is very old written a long time ago and it was working just fine. What I have done is changed the email sending code and specified the SSL and new Port for sending the SMS. Other then that it was not giving error before.

So below is the function which is used to generate the files when the user submit the forms. There are multiple files generated for each form.

```
   private bool GenerateFile()
        {
        string strSupportDocFile=string.Empty;
        string strBespokeFile=string.Empty;

        EFormDetails objEFormDetails=new EFormDetails();
        DataRow drEForm=objEFormDetails.ResultRow;

        string strDirPath = Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID);
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(strDirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirPath);
            }
            StreamWriter ef_File;
            StringBuilder strFile=new StringBuilder();

            ef_File = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EF_COMP_FILENAME));
            if(objEFormDetails._EF_COMP != string.Empty)
            {                   
                strFile.Append(objEFormDetails._EF_COMP);
                ef_File.WriteLine(strFile.ToString());
                ef_File.Close();
                sbOnFloppyComp=strFile;
            }

            ef_File  = null;
            strFile=null;

            StringBuilder ef_Cost=new StringBuilder();
            strFile=new StringBuilder();

            ef_File = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EF_COST_FILENAME));

            if(objEFormDetails._EF_COST != string.Empty)
            {
                strFile.Append(objEFormDetails._EF_COST);
                ef_File.WriteLine(strFile.ToString());
                ef_File.Close();
                sbOnFloppyCost=strFile;
            }

            GetMemberData();
            GetOtherDirectorsData();
            if(base.IsGuestUser())
            {
                string strEmailBody;
                strEmailBody=GenerateBody();
                string strpackage = strEmailBody;
                GetPackageDetails(strpackage);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text=ex.Message.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

GetMemberData() function:

```
private void GetMemberData()
    {
        EFormDetails objEFormDetails = new EFormDetails();
        DataRow drEForm = objEFormDetails.ResultRow;
        if (drEForm != null)
        {
            string strDirPath = Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID);
            eFormation.Business.EFDIR efdir = new eFormation.Business.EFDIR();
            eFormationResult objResult;
            objResult = efdir.LoadEFDIRData(Convert.ToInt64(drEForm[EFORMData.ID_FIELD]), Convert.ToString(drEForm[EFORMData.COMPANYNAME_FIELD]));// + "  " + Convert.ToString(drEForm[EFORMData.LIMITED_FIELD])==DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : drEForm[EFORMData.LIMITED_FIELD])));//give efromid adn comapany name

            if (!Directory.Exists(strDirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirPath);
            }
            StreamWriter swMember;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            swMember = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EFDIR_MEMBER_FILENAME));

            for (int i = 0; i < objResult.ResultData.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(objResult.ResultTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            }
            sbOnFloppyMember = sb;
            swMember.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            swMember.Close();
            sb = null;
            swMember = null;
        }
    }
```

GetOtherDirectorsData() function:

```
private void GetOtherDirectorsData()
    {
        EFormDetails objEFormDetails = new EFormDetails();
        DataRow drEForm = objEFormDetails.ResultRow;
        if (drEForm != null)
        {
            string strDirPath = Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID);
            eFormationResult objResult;
            eFormation.Business.EFODIR objefodir = new eFormation.Business.EFODIR();
            objResult = objefodir.LoadEFODIRData(Convert.ToInt64(drEForm[EFORMData.ID_FIELD]));//change
            if (!Directory.Exists(strDirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirPath);
            }
            StreamWriter swMember;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            swMember = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EFODIR_OTHERDIRECTOR_FILENAME));

            for (int i = 0; i < objResult.ResultData.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(objResult.ResultTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

            }
            sbOnFloppyOtherDirectors = sb;
            swMember.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            swMember.Close();
            sb = null;
            swMember = null;
        }
    }
```

GetPackageDetails() function:

```
private void GetPackageDetails(String strBodyContent)
    {
        StreamWriter ef_File;
        StringBuilder strFile = new StringBuilder();

        ef_File = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EF_PACKAGE_FILENAME));
        ef_File.WriteLine(strBodyContent);
        ef_File.Close();
        sbOnFloppyComp = strFile;
    }
```

Now all these above mentioned methods are used to create the files.
Now all these files created are added as attachments in the

```
MailAttachment attachment = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EF_COMP_FILENAME));
            mEmailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            MailAttachment attachment = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EFDIR_MEMBER_FILENAME));
            mEmailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            MailAttachment attachment = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath(@"Attachment/" + Session.SessionID + @"/" + ConstantsData.EF_COST_FILENAME));
            mEmailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

See any error?

I have just added these two lines as the email server is now changed to Office 365.

```
mEmailMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);
                mEmailMessage.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", true);
```

Comment: single server or server farm? same request or different request? It is possible that a worker thread has a lock on it (the creating thread) and another worker thread is trying to read it (thus locked).

Comment: It is a single server. Simple asp.net hosting. Application is web form. How to check the lock on the file? Is it possible?

Comment: if you only have one server and the file is emailed in the same request as it is written to disk, then there musty be an issue with either a) the saving code or b) the emailing code or c) an external resource such as a virus scanner etc. When you say it works locally, do you mean is VS or hosted locally is IIS. Try locally in IIS and see what happens.

Comment: If the only purpose of the file is to include it as an attachment on the email, I like to not write the file to disc. Instead, pass it around as a byte array or as an [Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: sounds like you have some issues with how you are using and or creating the instance of the `Stream and || FileStream` however it would truly benefit you if you would show the code being that we do not have access to your domain nor can we see what you see.. it's counter productive to post all that text without showing the code in question..

Comment: @MethodMan I have specified the functions for creating the files. Kindly check the code now. Thanks

Comment: wrap your email around a `using(){}` block so you do not have to explicitly call any `Dispose()` Methods as well also where are you actually calling the email.Send()` Method...?

Comment: I just mentioned the code lines for adding attachments. Send is called after it but I think David is right about file lock in attachments.

Comment: This question does not shows any research effort? What kind of research should I show. The thing that want to be smart people does not understand on this forum is that they just discourage everyone by down voting. I am not here to make points but this discourage. I have just not shared all of my code initially but explained my problem quite well that what I have done and what was before and also mentioned that I don't know whether it is problem with code or server because code is fine and was working fine. But if you have the power to down vote then use it appropriately. Not for your fun.

Comment: Down vote is usually given by those people who has nothing to comment or nothing to share on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you dispose of your Attachments and your mail message. Otherwise a lock can linger.

```
                mail.Attachments.Dispose()
                mail.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks. I also just found out that there is locking issue when mail.Attachments.Add(attachment); is called. I also have read that I need to call the Dispose for each attachment and then finally call Dispose for MailMessage object. I am using System.Web.Mail and currently cannot not upgrade to System.Net.Mail. There is no Dispose method in it so will mEmailMessage.Attachments.Clear(); do the work?

Comment: Not real sure, but I think System.Web.Mail.MailMessage has a Dispose(). I would do your Attachments.Clear() and then Message.Dispose(). Hopefully this will do the trick.